# Trying to scan an input that loops, with a delimiter, into 2 string arrays

Tags: arrays, for-loop, java.util.scanner, delimiter

The code is like this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Phonebook{
public static void main(String[]args){

Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
scan.useDelimiter("[\\s#\\s]");
int x = 0;

System.out.print("Enter the number of contacts you want to add: ");
    x = scan.nextInt(); scan.nextLine();
    String []name = new String[x];
    String []num  = new String[x];

for(int i=0; i<x; i++){
    System.out.print("\nInput contact with the format <Name>#<Phone number> : ");
    name[i] = scan.next();
    num[i]  = scan.next();
}

System.out.println("\n\n\n\n\nYOUR CONTACT LIST");
for(int i=0; i<x; i++){
    System.out.println("=========================");
    System.out.println("Contact #"+i);
    System.out.println("Name    : "+name[i]);
    System.out.println("Phone number : "+num[i]);
}
}}
```

It seems to work AT FIRST, but when I want multiple contacts to be added it starts acting up.
Here's how it looks when compiled & run:

```
Enter the number of contacts you want to add: 4

Input contact with the format <Name>#<Phone number> : asdf#asdf

Input contact with the format <Name>#<Phone number> : qwer#qwer

Input contact with the format <Name>#<Phone number> :
Input contact with the format <Name>#<Phone number> : zxcv#zxcv

YOUR CONTACT LIST
==========================
Contact #0
Name         : asdf
Phone number : asdf
=========================
Contact #1
Name         :
Phone number : qwer
=========================
Contact #2
Name         : qwer
Phone number :
=========================
Contact #3
Name         : zxcv
Phone number : zxcv

Press any key to continue . . .
```

Why did it skip the 1st index's Name & 2nd index's Phone number; and went back to normal on the 3rd index?
Just to note, the phone number is intended to be a string & I'm a beginner student.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding a

```
scan.nextLine();
```

to read the next line. Your second "name" is probably the line end of the first (!) contact because you didn't read all input.